# How to save the order of records given by User

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i know my question doesnt explain anything but here is the scenario. I have a `registration` table with `classid` `userid` and `arenaid` and other necessary ids for registration. Now `user` will register into event and `event organisor` can see all the registration. When `event organisor` sees the registration i display all registration grouped by `Arena` first and than group by `Classes`. Lets say in `Arena 1` under `Class 1` there are 5 users who registered which are as follows

```
1 John
2 Micheal
3 Leslie
4 Mickey
5 Stephen
```

Now i want the `user` to be able to drag and drop those registrations and change the order of entry,which is not a problem and can be done using `jquery` but i cant figure out how should i save the order of registration in database so that when `event organisor` visits that same page again he/she can see the order selected by him/her as last time.

Should i create a new table and save the `id` of registered users as array and when `event organisor` changes the order,i should update that array and display according to that array? or is there any other simpler way???

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ has the triggers buit in for the ajax update

Answer (score 1):

Have an extra `int` column in your `registration` table `registration_order` and set this to the order of the user.

Comment: that means every time drag and drop happens i need to call `ajax` method and change the order right?

Comment: Yep, you will need to run an update on the all the records for that group and reassign the order. A better name would probably be `registration_sequence` or similar